# Asyncio gather returning None

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have this code

```
async def scrap_zalando(url):
    # executing block of code
    return price, sizes

async def scrape_urls(urls):
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(scrap_zalando(url)) for url in urls]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results
# lis is a list of two url's 
results = asyncio.run(scrape_urls(lis))
print(results)
```

This the output I am getting

```
[('84,69\xa0zł', ['L', 'XL', 'XXL']), None]
```

Why is it none? I was debugging function using prints and all the values that I am returning were correct

Comment: I have discovered that the issue was because I was using os.remove(file) in my async def function, but I dont know why it happes